# How to store some field as Json when importing Excel in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I try to import Excel to Laravel when some field merges as JSON in the customer's table. In my case, I try to merge some fields like `berar_badan,` `usia,` etc., on the `other_data` field. I tried this code but failed.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
]);

$file = $request->file('file');
$data = Excel::toArray(new CustomerImport, $file);

DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    foreach ($data[0] as $d) {
        //skip header
        if ($d == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $email = Customer::where('email', $d['email_address'])->first();
        $otherData = array_shift($d);
        
        if (!$email) {
            $customer = Customer::create([
                // 'source' => $d['source'],
                'source_detail' => $d['source_detail'],
                'source_sub_detail' => $d['source_detail'],
                'name' => $d['customer_name'],
                'phone_1' => $d['phone_number_1'],
                'email' => $d['email_address'],
                'dob' => $d['dob'],
                'address' => $d['address'],
                'village' => $d['kelurahan'],
                'district' => $d['kecamatan'],
                'regency' => $d['kabupaten'],
                'province' => $d['provinsi'],
                'hpl' => $d['hpl'],
                'parent_type' => $d['parent_type'],
                'password' => Hash::make($d['phone_number_1']),
                'client_id' => Session::get('client_id'),
                'other_data' => $otherData
            ]);

            DB::table('customer_children')->insert([
                'customer_id' => $customer->id,
                'name' => $d['child_name'],
                'dob' => $d['child_dob'],
                'gender' => $d['children_gender'],
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
        }
    }
    DB::commit();

    Alert::success('Success', 'Success upload data customer.');
    
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: What is the error?